# Handle incompatible matrices shapes in tf-idf

Tags: python, pandas, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to match company names of two different data frames df1 and df2. I am trying to implement tf-idf and cosine similarity on two columns - company1 in df1 and company2 in df2.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
v = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix1 = v.fit_transform(df1['company1'])
tfidf_matrix2 = v.fit_transform(df2['company2'])
cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix2, tfidf_matrix1)
```

This gives me an error:

```
ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] 
== 31089 while Y.shape[1] == 46844
```

This is probably because:

```
tfidf_matrix1.shape
```

gives me (78684, 46844) as the output. And -

```
tiff_matrix2.shape
```

gives me (39462, 31089) as the output. How do I rectify this error?

Comment: Is that really an error?  Do you expect the matrices to have the same shape or not?  If you don't expect them to have the same shape, then how do you want to "fix" the problem?

Comment: I am new to tf-idf. I want to find the cosine similarity between each company name , so that i can find the matching companies. My primary goal is to find the matching companies. I don't know how to proceed further because of this error.

Answer (score 4):

Basically:

`tfidf_matrix1 = v.fit_transform(df1['company1'])`

`tfidf_matrix2 = v.transform(df2['company2'])`

You need to fit once and after only transform.

Comment: Does it matter if the strings are different lengths?  I have the same number of rows for each data frame, but keep getting a: ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 27 while Y.shape[1] == 508. For me, first DF is headline, and second DF is article Bodies

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you are doing the fit_transform on both of your datasets.  The first step of fitting is to learn the vocabulary that you are using in your documents (ignoring hashingTF), so matrix 1 has 31089 unique terms, while 2 has 46844.

Cosine similarity then multiplies the two matrices to produce the similarity, so each column matches to a different term.  However because you fit twice, you are using two different vocabularies.  You need to fit once, and transform twice.